# installing node dependencies manually

Tags: npm, npm-install

As I've learned from SO topics dependencies for node aren't installed automatically on the fly since npm version 3. I'm running version 3.5.2 and I get these warnings when running `npm install --no-optional`:

```
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.0.2 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.0.2 requires a peer of @typescript-eslint/parser@2.x but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@5.0.2 requires a peer of eslint@6.x but none was installed.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none was installed.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev

npm ERR! Missing: react-router-dom@^5.1.2
npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 does not satisfy @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.8.0
npm ERR!
```

How do I install these manually ?

I tried:

```
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@2.*
npm install eslint@6.*
npm install typescript@*
```

but that did no good. Still throws those warnings.

**I got little bit further:**

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^5.16.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'client'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mark/.npm/_logs/2019-10-04T20_26_24_111Z-debug.log
```

Comment: You tried with not * on end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following for each peer dependency to install that and remove the error.

```
$ npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint
```

For another error,

```
No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^5.16.0.
```

Please run `npm view @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`.
Then, you can see that highest version of @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin is 2.3.2 now. This `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^5.16.0` version not exists.

Comment: Those optional dependencies are meant for OS X. I'm running Ubuntu and running the command without the flag I get errors.

Comment: @mr_incredible, did you try with `sudo`? like `sudo npm install`?

Comment: can you please attach errors log when running with `npm install`?

Comment: @mr_incredible, please try with `npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint`.

Comment: I got little bit further now. But it still complains.

Comment: I ran `npm install --save-dev @typescript-eslint` and then `sudo npm install` but keep getting errors. Is this happening to all Ubuntu users I wonder ...

Comment: I'm kinda happy that I'm unemployed right now because I don't wanna be killing all day on dependencies as opposed to doing an actual work.

Comment: Do you still get same warning? Or getting other dependencies warning?

Comment: I get less errors but the rest of the errors I listed below the "I got little bit further" note in the post.

Comment: Please check my updated answer for the rest of the errors.

Comment: This @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^5.16.0 version not exists.

Comment: Yeah I noticed too. I removed "5.16.0" from `package.json` file and left just a blank string instead and then it ran like a charm. Blank string means that it will download and install latest available version I assume. A day well spent.